# Selecting rows whose first column value appears at least once in a list

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, any

Suppose that:

```
A = [1,22,33; 2,44,55; 2,66,77]
id = [2 3 5]
```

I am trying to select all the matrix `A` rows if the value of their first column appears in `id` at least once, without using a loop.

Hence, starting from:

```
A =

 1    22    33
 2    44    55
 2    66    77
```

in this example I would like to get the following:

```
2    44    55
2    66    77
```

what is the easier way to do this?
Many thanks.

Comment: Use `ìsmember` to create a logical index that will select the rows: `A(ismember(A(:,1), id),:)`

Comment: it works thanks, if you put it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Alright, done :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to create a logical index that will select the rows:

```
A(ismember(A(:,1), id),:)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`any`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) and [`bsxfun(@eq, ...)`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead of `ismember`:

```
A(any(bsxfun(@eq, A(:,1).', id(:)), 1), :)
```

Or, starting at Matlab version R2016b, you can replace `bsxfun(@eq, ...)` by just `==` thanks to [implicit singleton expansion](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html):

```
A(any(A(:,1).'==id(:), 1), :)
```